# Copy values by Google script in Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to copy information from source sheet to target sheet every 5 minutes as in this example

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/s0cFHaIvWV0;context-place=forum/docs

It is working fine if it is copying plain values. The problem is, if the information in source sheet is a formula, it will copy the formula instead of the value in the cell.

How should I amend my script?

```
function createTimeDrivenTrigger() {
ScriptApp.newTrigger('myFunction')
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(5)
    .create()
}

function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 2"), //target sheet
    sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1"), //source sheet
    startRow = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
        .getProperty('start') || 1;
try {
    sheet1.getRange(startRow, 1, 4, sheet1.getLastColumn())
        .copyTo(sheet2.getRange(sheet2.getLastRow() + 1 || 1, 1));
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
        .setProperty('start', parseInt(startRow) + 4);
} catch (e) {
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
        .deleteProperty('start');
    ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(function (t) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the .getValues() on the range you want to copy

Documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

***Edit***

Here is an example of how to use the `getRange()` function.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var range = sheet.getRange("B2:D4");
```

From your example, you have `sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1")` as the source where you want the data to come from.

So, if you want to get a specific range of values from `Sheet 1` you can use the `getRange()` method on your `sheet1` variable.

E.g. You want to get the range of values in the cells A1, B1, C1, and D1, you would add the `getRange()` method to `sheet1` as follows:

`sheet1.getValues("A1:D1")`

I hope that explains things clearly.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...the problem is I have very little background in programming. I think I should put getValues somewhere but I just can't get the script running...

Comment: I've updated my answer with further explanation. Hope that works for you.

Comment: It is workable now. I added {contentsOnly:true} in the CopyTo script.And I specified the area by your help, many thanks!